# Unable to convert between encodings using iconv

Tags: c++, unicode, iconv

I'm trying to convert a string in German language to UTF-16 using iconv, but in vain. Here's the code for it:

```
#include <iconv.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

using namespace std;

const size_t BUF_SIZE=1024;

class IConv {
        iconv_t ic_;
public:
        IConv(const char* to, const char* from)
            : ic_(iconv_open(to,from))    { }
        ~IConv() { iconv_close(ic_); }

         bool convert(char* input, char* output, size_t& out_size) {
            size_t inbufsize = strlen(input)+1;
            return iconv(ic_, &input, &inbufsize, &output, &out_size);
         }
};

int main(void)
{
    char str1[BUF_SIZE] = "tägelîch";
    char str2[BUF_SIZE] = "something else";
    IConv ic("en_US.UTF-8","UTF16LE");
    bool ret;

    cout << str1 << endl;
    size_t outsize = BUF_SIZE;  //you will need it
    ret = ic.convert(str1, str2, outsize);
    if (ret == false) {
        cout << "iconv failed: " << errno << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cout << str2 << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out
tägelîch
something else
```

If the from encoding type is changed to `ISO-8859-1`, the result is the same.

On the other hand, iconv utility works fine from the command prompt:

```
$ echo "TägelîcH" | iconv -f "ISO-8859-1" -t UTF-16LE
T▒▒gel▒▒cH
```

`iconv --list` shows that both `ISO-8859-1` and `UTF-16LE` are supported. What am I missing?

Is C++ in any way causing this behaviour?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Isn't C++.

Your code has a lot of problem.

1) if I'm not wrong, you switch in-code with out-code; with `ic("en_US.UTF-8","UTF16LE")` (and `iconv_open(to,from)`) you're asking to convert from "UTF16LE" to "en_US.UTF-8"; if I understand well, you want the contrary

2) I don't know in your platform, but my Debian `iconv` doesn't support the "en_US.UTF-8" encodind; try with `iconv --list` to see if `iconv` in your platform supports it

3) You don't test if `iconv_open(to,from)` return `iconv_t(-1)`, the error value

4) You return `bool` from convert but `iconv()` return a `size_t`; in case of error, `iconv()` returns `size_t(-1)` that, converted in bool, become `true` (no error, if I understan well)

5) You don't test the value of the third argument passed to `convert()`; it should be zero after calling the function (or part of the input stream is unconverted)

6) when you initialize `str1` to "tägelîch", you initialize it in ISO-8859-1, not in UTF-8

Briefly, if I'm not wrong, you pass a to-encoding that isn't in the list of encoding supported by iconv. The constructor of your `IConv` class initialize `cv_`  with `iconv_t(-1)` (error value). When you call the `convert()` method, `iconv()` fail and return `size_t(-1)` (error value) that is returned as `true` (no error value) by `convert()`.

The following code isn't perfect but I hope it can help you

```
#include <iconv.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

using namespace std;

const size_t BUF_SIZE=1024;

class IConv {

   iconv_t ic_;

   public:
        IConv (const char* to, const char* from)
           : ic_(iconv_open(to,from)) {
              if ( iconv_t(-1) == ic_ )
                 throw std::runtime_error("error from iconv_open()");
            }

        ~IConv ()
         { if ( iconv_t(-1) != ic_) iconv_close(ic_); }

         bool convert (char* input, char* output, size_t& out_size) {
            size_t inbufsize = strlen(input)+1;
            return
                   (size_t(-1)
                      != iconv(ic_, &input, &inbufsize, &output, &out_size))
                && (0U == inbufsize);
         }
};

int main(void)
{
    char str1[BUF_SIZE] = "tägelîch";
    char str2[BUF_SIZE] = "something else";
    IConv ic("UTF16LE", "ISO_8859-1");
    bool ret;
    size_t outsize = BUF_SIZE;

    ret = ic.convert(str1, str2, outsize);
    if (ret == false) {
        cout << "iconv failed: " << errno << endl;
    }
    else {
       cout << "outsize[" << outsize << "]\n";
       cout << "str1[" << str1 << "]\n";
       cout << "str2[" << str2 << "]\n";

       for ( int i = 0 ; i < (BUF_SIZE - outsize) ; ++i )
          if ( str2[i] )
             cout << "str2[" << i << "]=[" << int(str2[i]) << "]("
                << str2[i] << ")\n";
    }

    return ret ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistakes in the code. It works fine now.